# What is the meaning of "que" and "cual" without an accent mark?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres, conjunciones

What does "que" and "cual" mean without an accent mark? How do they compare when to each other? How do they compare to their accent-marked form?

Answer (score 8):

*Qué* and *cuál* are [interrogatory pronouns](http://spanish.about.com/cs/grammar/a/que_vs_cual.htm), and are thus used when asking questions (see [relevant question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22/question-words-que-versus-cual)):

> ¿**Qué** ha ocurrido? → **What** has happened?
>
> *¿**Cuál** es tu número de teléfono?* → **What** is your phone number?

Qué can also be an exclamative adjective (if it is used before a noun):

> *¿**Qué** hora es?* → **What** time is it?

Qué can also be an exclamative adverb (if it is used before an adjective):

> ¡**Qué** guapa es! → **How** pretty she is!

*Qué* can also be used in exclamations (not only in questions). So *qué* (with accent mark) can be used in direct or indirect questions and exclamations:

> ¿**Qué** has hecho? → **What** have you done?(direct question)
>
> No sé **qué** hacer. → I don't know **what** to do. (indirect question)
>
> ¡**Qué** guapa es! → **How** pretty she is! (direct exclamation)
>
> Ya sabe **qué** dura es la vida. → He already knows **how** hard life is. (indirect exclamation)

Without accents, they are [relative pronouns](http://spanish.about.com/od/pronouns/a/que_relative_pronouns.htm):

> *Rebeca es la mujer con **la que** vas a viajar.* → Rebeca is the woman with **whom** you are going to travel.
> *Rebeca es la mujer con **la cual** vas a viajar* → Rebeca is the woman with **whom** you are going to travel.

*Que* (without the accent) can also be a conjunction:

> *Quiero **que** vengas.* → I want **that** you go. / I want you to go.
> *Llámame **antes de que** llegues.* → Call me **before** you arrive.

Answer (score 2):

(1) **"Que"** *(without accent)* is equivalent to **"that"**. For example:

> I guess **that** you are Anne.
>
> Supongo **que** eres Anne.

(2) **"Cual"** *(without accent)* is quite equivalent to **"whom"**. For example:

> Anne is the woman **whom** Jhon got married.
>
> Anne es la mujer con la **cual** Jhon se casó.

(3) Their accent marked form is used when asking. All interrogatory pronouns in spanish have accent (e.g. qué, cuál, cómo, dónde). For example:

> ¿**Cuál** es tuyo?
>
> **Which** is yours?

Another example:

> ¿**Qué** es eso?
>
> **What** is that?

Comment: You should've mentioned why *que = that*, and just because it's a subordinated clause.

Comment: You can always edit and improve answers :)

Answer (score 1):

This also applies to the *defining* or *non-defining* relative clauses.

We use *que* for the relative pronouns *who* & *which*:

1. This is the nurse who helped me = Esta es la enfermera **que** me ayudó.
2. This is the farm which was built in 1978 = Esta es la granja **que** se construyó en 1978.

However, this can be even more complicated because we introduce **que** in clauses where English sentences don't have them:

1. I think I'll go = Creo **que** iré.
   Considering that **que** often triggers the subjunctive in present or past depending of the context:
2. I asked you to bring it = Te pedí **que** lo traigas/trajeras.
   In this case, **verb + object + infinitive** often triggers a **que** in a Spanish sentence. We could also have *te pedí traerlo*, invoking the infinitive and no **que** is shown.