# Doubt over using "como" or "cómo"

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

From the lyrics of [a song](http://open.spotify.com/track/3edelsDfS4FW5vZp6J06Zc):

> y lo que más me gusta de ti
>    es como tú pronuncias mi nombre

Which is correct here, "como" with or without accent?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1642/12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cómo` (actually, not only `cómo` but *qué, cuál/es, quién/es, cuán, cuánto/a/os/as, cuándo, dónde and adónde*) has the accent when it is an interrogative or exclamative pronoun:

> ¿Cómo estás?
>
> ¿Cómo dijo que se llama?
>
> ¡Cómo ha subido la gasolina!
>
> ¡Cómo has crecido!
>
> No sé cómo vamos a llegar hasta allí sin coche.

They don't have the accent when they have a different function, which for ["como"](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=s3kpSlOhuD6v706948) (without an accent) means to be used as an adverb. Since in the example it has the function of a modal adverb (has the meaning of *"la manera en que"* / "the way in which") it doesn't need the accent.

> Me gusta como pronuncias mi nombre (Me gusta la manera en que pronuncias mi nombre)
>
> La manera como canta Juan no me gusta. Suena como un gato aullando.
>
> Me gusta su acento. Suena como Antonio Banderas.

Check also [this link](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-que-cuales-quienes-como-cuan-cuantoaosas-cuando-donde-y-adonde) and [this other](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NRljHeeb2D6KmUqa9B) if you want to compare more usages of `como` and `cómo`.

Comment: remember the open signs (¿ ¡).

Comment: @Rodrigo, Gracias. No me olvido de ellos cuando escribo en español, pero es uno de los puñeteros símbolos que todavía no he encontrado en el teclado de mi ordenador. Quizá debería emplear 10 minutitos en buscar en google dónde están, y librarme de este problema... De momento voy a editar la respuesta con un copia-pega de los que me has dejado :-)

Comment: Good explanation, thanks! (Try alt-shift-1 for ¡, or [check this out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks#Input_methods).)