# Difference between "Que" and "cual"

Tags: gramática, preguntas

I came to know from the duolingo application that Que means what. And is an interrogative sentence:

```
What is the question?
```

It translates to Spanish as

```
¿Cuál es la pregunta?
```

Why not?

```
¿Qué es la pregunta?
```

Comment: "Cuál" and "Qué" would be needing they accent here as they are [interrogative pronouns](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12006/5481)

Comment: Watch must video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKzj-PWE hope it will help

Answer (score 6):

The sentence *"¿Qué es la pregunta?"* does not make sense in Spanish. It can be understood as "*what is the definition of the question?*", but grammatically sounds bad.

Here I paste a graph showing the difference between *qué* and *cuál*. (I don't know the source, only found among my docs).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It can be hard to pick up on the nuances of this issue. **Cuál** means 'Which' (as in *which one*?), and is usually the right word to use when followed by 'to be', as in *¿Cuál es la pregunta?* **Qué** is used when immediately followed by the noun, as in *¿Qué pregunta tienes?*

Comment: Brief, right and easy.

Answer (score 1):

**Cuál es la pregunta**.
*You asking basically what's the question.*

**Qué es la pregunta**?
*In other cases could have sense, but not here.
For example: What is this?
Would be: Qué es esto? ("Cuál es esto" doesn't exist)*

Translated in English would be as you say "What is the question" both, with the difference that the first has sense and the second doesn't.