# When do I use "cual" vs "que"?

Tags: preguntas

I understand both often translate to English as "what" or "which" and "that", respectively.

My professor told me that *cual* is often used when presented with a choice while *que* is used when asked to explain something. However it seems that these reasons often apply to the same instances. Please let me know if there is an easier way to figure out when to use these two words.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! This is indeed a very interesting question, but unfortunately it has been asked previously in this site. Please check [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22/12637) and its answers and see if your doubt has been solved. If not, please edit your question and tell us why do you still has doubts.